# Confusing tensor product in R. Adler and J. Taylor's "Random fields and geometry", in their definition of partial derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, partial-derivative

On pages 22-23 of Robert J. Adler and Jonathan E. Taylor's *Random Fields and Geometry*, the mean square partial derivative of a random field is defined as follows: (verbatim quote)

Choose a point $t \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and a sequence of $k$ "directions" $t_{1}',...,t_{k}' $ in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, so that $t' = (t_{1}',...,t_{k}') \in \otimes ^{k} \mathbb{R}^{N} $, the $k$-fold tensor product $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with itself. We say that $f$ has a $k$th-order $L^{2}$ partial derivative at $t$, in the direction $t'$, which we denote by $D^{k}_{L^{2}}f(t,t') $, if the limit
$$D^{k}_{L^{2}}f(t,t') \overset{\Delta}{=} \underset{h_{1},...,h_{k} \rightarrow 0}{lim} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{k}h_{i}}F\left(t, \sum_{i=1}^{k}h_{i}t_{i}' \right)$$
exists in $L^{2} $, where $F(t,t')$ is the symmetrized difference
$$F(t,t') = \sum_{s \in \{0,1\}^{k}} (-1)^{k-\sum_{i=1}^{k}s_{i}}f\left(t + \sum_{i=1}^{k}s_{i}t_{i}' \right) $$
and the limit above is interpreted sequentially, i.e. first send $h_{1}$ to $0$, then $h_{2}$, etc.
(end quote)

This is confusing for two reasons: first, the definitions of $F$ and $t'$ as they are given imply that the second argument is meant to be a element of $\otimes^{k}\mathbb{R}^{N} $, however in the definition of $D^{k}_{L^{2}}f(t,t') $, $\sum_{i=1}^{k}h_{i}t_{i}'$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, if it were an element of the tensor product, it would be written as a tensor product.

Second, even putting this aside by assuming a mistake in writing, the very fact that the second argument of $F$ is a tensor poses problems. Taking $k=2$ for simplicity, we know that if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ then $(\lambda a )\otimes b = a \otimes (\lambda b) = \lambda (a \otimes b)$. However in the definition of $F$, it is clear that $F(t,a\otimes (\lambda b))$ and $F(t,(\lambda a)\otimes b) $ are not equal in general. Which means $F$ is not well-defined.

Were it not for the sentence "the k-fold tensor product $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with itself", I would have assumed it was a mistake, and that the authors meant to use \oplus rather than \otimes. I considered using $\oplus^{k}\mathbb{R}^{N} $ anyway when applying the theorem I need (theorem 1.4.2 page 23), only the proof seems to use the characteristics of $\otimes^{k}\mathbb{R}^{N} $ as a manifold and I don't know that it still works when using $\oplus^{k}\mathbb{R}^{N} $, which might have very different properties as a manifold.

Note that the book has a part on tensor calculus (7.2), however this part does not use the notation $V \otimes W$ with $V$ and $W$ spaces, instead $\otimes$ is only used between tensors. Maybe this means that the definition of tensor product in this particular case is different than usual?

Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: It’s clearly abuse of notation, with the original ordered $k$-tuple. However, the point is that symmetry of higher-order partial derivatives suggests that the input $t’$ should be a symmetric $k$-tensor.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, could you elaborate a little more, please? I'm not 100% certain I understand what you mean